# Reactstrap component cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, reactstrap

I created a simple typescript react app with `react-create-app` library.

After that, I installed reactstrap and bootsrap and tried implement a simple reacstrap button to my code

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button} from "reactstrap";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

function App () {
    return <Button>Button</Button>;
}

export default App;
```

After start I got the error

```
'Button' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'Button' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/krolov/work/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
        Type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
          Property 'children' is missing in type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>' but required in type 'ReactPortal'.
```

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-cdn-5pfqt8?file=/src/App.js. Please make sure the example is a [mcve] showing the problem

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
First of all, you are using js instead of ts and error is typescript related
second I can't reproduce it at codesandbox I think cause there is a little bit different lib setup.
Anyway, your comment helps me to fix the issue. I downgrade @types/react and everything starts work perfect

I believe it's somewhere related with typescript version and @types/react tag, but have not too much passion to find exact problem